# Calculate the bearings to the furthest point of a trip

Tags: r, gps, angle, direction, bearing

I have GPS data and I am trying to calculate the bearing to the furthest part of the trip. My data looks like this:

> `Time          Lat         Long
>    18:11:25   -38.621449  142.931061
>    18:13:25   -38.62212   142.929871
>    18:15:33   -38.623333  142.92868
>   ...
>    23:16:26   -38.793068  142.827881
>    23:18:54   -38.795414  142.838516
>    23:23:02   -38.795803  142.839066
>   ... 
>    09:59:49   -38.621532  142.930786`

I am trying to calculate the bearing between the starting point (-38.621449 142.931061) and the furthest point (-38.793068,142.827881).

I have been able to do this by manually extracting the 2 locations from the spreadsheet and calculating the bearing using my script:

```
`   bearing <- function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2){
lat1 <- angledim(lat1,"degrees","radians")
lon1 <- angledim(lon1,"degrees","radians")
lat2 <- angledim(lat2,"degrees","radians")
lon2 <- angledim(lon2,"degrees","radians")

dlon <- lon1 - lon2


theta <- atan2(cos(lat2)*sin(dlon),cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dlon))
theta <- angledim(theta,"radians","degrees")
theta <- (theta+360) %% 360
theta   
}`
```

Is there an easier way to calculate this without going through endless spreadsheets?

(Apologies in advance if things are not formatted properly, this is my first question!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the earth.bear function from the fossil package here but you could use your own custom written one.

```
earth.bear(mydata$Long[1],mydata$Lat[1],
       tail(mydata$Long, n=1),tail(mydata$Lat, n=1))
```